# Error with passing in the same variable into multiple parts of SQL statement

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So I have a Node.js query that should pass in these three values and update a specific column by a specific amount for a user with a specific id:

```
await client.query(sqlStatement, [columnName, changeBy, id])
```

The 'sqlStatement' looks like:

```
'UPDATE tableName SET ($1) = ($1) + ($2) WHERE id = ($3)'
```

As you can see, it should pass in the values such that the SQL statement looks like:

```
'UPDATE tableName SET columnName = columnName + changeBy WHERE id = id'
```

I've also tried to write sqlStatement as the below (and just pass in columnName twice into the query but this also results in an error:

```
'UPDATE tableName SET ($1) = ($2) + ($3) WHERE id = ($4)'
```

The error returned is error: syntax error at or near "$1".

Not sure how to fix this--any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that `node-postgres` [doesn't support query parameters for identifiers](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) and your column name after `SET` is an identifier. Also, even if this worked, unless `node-postgres` somehow substituted the entire `($1)` (with parentheses) for your value, you'd get

`ERROR:  source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression`.

If you wish to keep `node-postgres`, its [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20does%20not%20support%20parameters%20for%20identifiers.%20If%20you%20need%20to%20have%20dynamic%20database%2C%20schema%2C%20table%2C%20or%20column%20names%20(e.g.%20in%20DDL%20statements)%20use%20pg%2Dformat%20package%20for%20handling%20escaping%20these%20values%20to%20ensure%20you%20do%20not%20have%20SQL%20injection!) recommends to use [pg-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) in such cases, to build a dynamic SQL statement. If you consider alternatives, you can look into [Knex.js](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-update) that will build the queries for you, like so:

```js
knex('tableName')
   .update({ 
       columnName: knex.raw('?? + ?',['columnName',changeBy])
   })
   .where('id', id)
```

And in the meanwhile, as a workaround, you should be able to set your `sqlStatement` to a dynamic SQL query on your own:

```sql
do language plpgsql $$ begin execute format('UPDATE test SET %I = %I + %s WHERE id = %s','$1','$1',$2,$3); end$$;
```

and try with that. Note that I removed the parentheses from around the update column to avoid the multiple-column UPDATE error. What should happen is that `node-postgres` evaluates the above to

```sql
do language plpgsql $$ begin execute format('UPDATE test SET %I = %I + %s WHERE id = %s','col','col',51,72); end$$;
```

and pass it to PostgreSQL, which should execute it as

```sql
UPDATE test SET "col" = "col" + 51 WHERE id = 72;
```

From the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

- `%I` is for **I**dentifiers, that PostgreSQL will automatically quote if needed.
- `%L` is for string **L**iterals
- `%s` is for **s**imple **s**tring substitution, in the sense that it will not be quoted, so it can be used for numeric literals